# cgo on windows : naming of loaded dll

Tags: windows, go, gcc, cgo, gccgo

I am trying to use [gorocksdb](https://github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb) which is a cgo package wapping the rocksdb library on windows.

- I built the rocksdb library with vcpkg which gave me as output **rocksdb-shared.dll**. I set the build path to my PATH.
- I installed msys64 in order to have gcc
- I have set `CGO_CFLAGS="-I/path/to/rocksdb/include"` and
  `CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/rocksdb -lrocksdb -lstdc++ -lm -lz -lbz2 -lsnappy -llz4 -lzstd"`
- I have renammed **rocksdb-shared.dll** to **librocksdb.dll** because the linker requires the dll to start with `lib`
- I do the `go get ...` command
- I run my test go file and I get the error `The programer can't start because rocksdb-shared.dll is missing ...`
- If I rename it back to **rocksdb-shared.dll** the build fails because the linker can't find **librocksdb.dll**
- The only way to make it work is to have both **rocksdb-shared.dll** and **librocksdb.dll** in the PATH

Why the executable keeps loading **rocksdb-shared.dll**? I don't find any reference to it in the cgo package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.

I think I can't rename the compiled dll because the dll "reference" itself as this name. So it won't load properly.

To resolve my problem I just renamed the parameter in the LDFLAG from **-lrocksdb** to **-lrocksdb-shared** in both my environement variable and in this [file](https://github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb/blob/209fbe7c598c4e5b6da30d90fa1e70f80bb887d7/dynflag.go)